# Discord Markov Chain

Tags: javascript

Hey I'm having some issues around my Discord bot, I know the cause of the error but I do not know how to fix it.

```
const triggerFoo = ["hey"]
const triggerBar = ["bye"]

const responseFoo = ["Hi!", "Hello!", "Whatsup!"]
const responseBar = ["Goodbye!", "Cya later!", "Laters!"]

const responseHuh = ["Make up your mind!", "I'm not understanding you"]

// snippet a
if (message.content.includes(triggerFoo)) {
  message.channel.send(responseFoo[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 )]);
}
// snippet b
if (message.content.includes(triggerBar)) {
  message.channel.send(responseBar[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 )]);
}
// snippet c
if (message.content.includes(triggerFoo + triggerBar)) {
  message.channel.send(responseHuh[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 )]);
}
```

**My problem:** If snippet C gets executed, snippet A & B also gets executed thus resulting in 3 messages being send instead of responseHuh.

**My goal:** Look if 2 strings are being triggered if so: Execute a seperate response.

Comment: `if ( includes(A) || includes(B) ) { sendMessage(); }`

Comment: I've removed the tags for `artificial-intelligence`, `discord.js` and `markov-chains` as they don't really have much to do with the question. This is purely a JS syntax issue and knowledge of AI or Discord aren't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is causing the problem, here:

```
if (message.content.includes(triggerHello)) {
  message.channel.send(responseHello[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 )]);
}

if (message.content.includes(triggerPeter)) {
  message.channel.send(responsePeter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 )]);
}
...
```

If you want it to only fire once, which one do you want to have priority? The first? This is exactly what you use if/else for.

```
if (message.content.includes(triggerHello)) {
  message.channel.send(responseHello[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 )]);
} else if (message.content.includes(triggerPeter)) {
  message.channel.send(responsePeter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 )]);
} else {
  message.channel.send(responseHuh[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 )]);
}
```

Comment: Please check my edited posts, I kinda misinformed the issue

Comment: @fragile this answer is still correct, though. You can structure your responses to be in an if/else if/else chain, which will ensure you will trigger only one.